# NSJSONSerialization parsing response data

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, nsjsonserialization

I created a WCF service, which provides the following response to my POST operation:

```
"[{\"Id\":1,\"Name\":\"Michael\"},{\"Id\":2,\"Name\":\"John\"}]"
```

My call to JSONObjectWithData, doesn't return any error, yet I can't enumerate over the results, what am I doing wrong?

```
NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonParsingError];

NSLog(@"jsonList: %@", jsonArray);

if(!jsonArray)
{
    NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON:%@", jsonParsingError);
}
else
{
    // Exception thrown here.        
    for(NSDictionary *item in jsonArray)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", item);
    }
}
```

Comment: What type of exception gets thrown?

Comment: Does your NSLog output anything from the jsonArray?

Comment: @Jacob-Relkin - Exception is: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Comment: @Jeremy - here's the output from jsonArray: jsonList: [{"Id":1,"Name":"Michael"},{"Id":2,"Name":"John"}]

Comment: Are you sure that you're always returning an array even if the response only contains one item?

Comment: If you are getting an exception, then it's because of malformed json.

Comment: If the json is malformed, wouldn't jsonParsingError contain an error?

Comment: @MarkAdams - yes, I'm always returning an array. Within my service, regardless of number of items, it's always returning back an array.

Comment: @Jeremy - sorry about that. Ignore last comment, the jsonParsingError doesn't contain any error. Here's the NSLog output: Error parsing JSON:(null). Note that it's not jumping into the first block of the if statement, it's jumping to the else. I had added the NSLog for the error before the if block to check it's value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jeremy pointed out, you shouldn't escape the quotes in the JSON data. But also, you've quoted the return string. That makes it a JSON string, not an object, so when you decode it you've got a string, not a mutable array, which is why you get an error when you try to fast iterate... you're not able to fast iterate over a string.

Your actual JSON should look like: `[{"Id":1,"Name":"Michael"},{"Id":2,"Name":"John"}]`. No quotes, no escapes. Once you eliminate the quotes around your JSON object, your app won't crash anymore, but then you're going to get a JSON deserialization error for malformed data (the escapes).

Comment: thanks Jason. That was it. I realized that I coded my WCF service wrong. Instead of my return type being a string, which is was, it should be a List<>, and just the ResponseFormat should be json, and the rest takes care of itself. Because I returned an actual string, everything was escaped, and the whole string quoted.

Answer (score 3):

The likely cause is you are using the wrong foundation object.  Try changing NSMutableArray to NSDictonary.

**From:**

```
NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonParsingError];
```

**To:**

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonParsingError];
```

Comment: Sorry, my answer assumed you weren't getting an exception. But, since you've stated that you've gotten an exception in a comment above, it's very likely that your json is malformed. Your response shouldn't actually be sending escapes over.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. My output from fiddler is "[{\"Id\":1,\"Name\":\"Michael\"},{\"Id\":2,\"Name\":\"John\"}]", which has escapes. I'll update my wcf service so it's not sending escapes on the response.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing with NSJSONSerialization is easy, but I have also created a little framework that allows parsing JSON values directly into class objects, instead of dealing with dictionaries. Take a look, it might be helpful:
https://github.com/mobiletoly/icjson