# objective c calling wcf rest service request

Tags: objective-c, wcf, wcf-data-services, nsjsonserialization

I've been trying to look for online articles / tutorials on how to go about coding a request from a wcf service. I have the following web service uploaded to my server:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IUserAccountService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "UserLogIn?id={email}&password={password}")]
        AuthenticationToken UserLogIn(string email, string password);
    }
```

I'm getting really confused with the articles or SO questions that are related to it that  I've been finding:

eg:

- -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557040/objective-c-best-way-to-access-rest-api-on-your-iphone
- -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650296/nsjsonserialization-parsing-response-data

and finally stumbled upon this:

**http://iam.fahrni.ws/2011/10/16/objective-c-rest-and-json/**

So my question is, do I really need to use a restful frameworks to do a call to an api? If so which one is more recommended - **ASIHttpRequest** or **RestKit** or **AFNetworking**? Or can I just simple do it myself using the last link I mentioned? I really am not sure where to start.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922296/is-restkit-a-good-replacement-for-asihttprequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSURLConnection and NSJSONSerialization work fine.

edit: Some example code from one of my projects, edited for brevity.
fstr(...) is just a wrapper around [NSString stringWithFormat:...]
I call this code on a background thread with GCD. It's not thread safe.

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)buildGetRequestHeaderWithMethod:(NSString *)method
{
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
    initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fstr(@"%@%@", self.url, method)]];
  [request setTimeoutInterval:10.0];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
  [request setValue:self.key forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authentication"];
  [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  return request;
}

- (id)callMethod:(NSString *)method
{
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self buildGetRequestHeaderWithMethod:method];
  return [self sendRequest:request withMethod:method];
}

- (id)sendRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request withMethod:(NSString *)method
{
  NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
  NSError *error = nil;
  [state() pushNetworkActivity];
  NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
    returningResponse:&response error:&error];
  [state() popNetworkActivity];
  self.lastStatusCode = response.statusCode;
  // Bug in Cocoa. 401 status results in 0 status and NSError code -1012.
  if(error && [error code] == NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication)
  {
    [self interpretHTTPError:401 URLError:error forMethod:method];
    self.lastStatusCode = 401;
    return nil;
  }
  if(response.statusCode != 200)
  {
    [self interpretHTTPError:response.statusCode URLError:error forMethod:method];
    return nil;
  }
  id jsonResult = [self parseJsonResult:result];
  debug(@"%@", jsonResult);
  return jsonResult;
}


- (void)interpretHTTPError:(int)statusCode URLError:(NSError *)urlError
  forMethod:(NSString *)method
{
  NSString *message = fstr(@"HTTP status: %d", statusCode);
  if(statusCode == 0)
    message = [urlError localizedDescription];

#ifdef DEBUG
    message = fstr(@"%@ (%@)", message, method);
#endif

  if(self.alertUserOfErrors)
  {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      errorMessage (message);
    });
  }
  else
    debug(@"%@", message);
  self.lastErrorMessage = message;
}

- (id)parseJsonResult:(NSData *)result
{
  if( ! result)
    return nil;
  NSError *error = nil;
  id jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result
    options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
  if(error)
  {
    NSLog(@"JSONObjectWithData failed with error: %@\n", error);
    return nil;
  }
  return jsonResponse;
}
```

Comment: do you know of any example source code that i can look at so i can understand how the sequence works?

Comment: awesome, ill try it out in a bit! thank you! i might have a few questions too.

Comment: hi, so in your code, do you call the "callMethod" and will it return a parsed json already? and as a string? I'm trying to figure out if i can use this for retrieving model details? And if I can does returning an id be something i can use to assign to a new instance of that model? eg. Event {"Id":1,"EventName":"Test 1", "EventAddress":"address 1"}

Comment: as a follow up, what are these two lines for? **[request setValue:self.key forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authentication"];
  [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];**

Comment: It returns the parsed json as NSMutableDictionary/NSMutableArray objects with NSString, NSNumber, NSNull etc in the leaf nodes.

Comment: @gdubs Those lines are for setting HTTP header values. The authentication field is something the web service I use requires, you probably don't need it. If you want to understand what the content-type does, you can read documentation for the HTTP standard.

Comment: @Minthos : hii minthos, will you please give me some time, i want to consume wcf json request , i am trying to use your code snippet but some fields are not known to me like , [state() pushNetworkActivity], [state() popNetworkActivity], lastStatusCode, and statusCode, along , what should be the method calling sequence, and if its from the callMethod: then what is the argument of method callMethod: named method. You can help me only. Please.

Comment: @iShwar You can remove the calls to state() and lastStatusCode. CallMethod is the entry point. The method parameter is the last part of the url for the web service call.

Comment: @Minthos : thank you Minthos, i am going through it, Will let you know the success.