# objective c parsing returned json from wcf service

Tags: objective-c, wcf, wcf-data-services, nsjsonserialization

So I asked this question recently and I was able to make it work

[objective c calling wcf rest service request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314316/objective-c-calling-wcf-rest-service-request)

Here's my code

```
NSString *urlStringRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://service.mydomain.com/UserAccountService.svc/UserLogin?id=%@&pword=%@", email, incPassword];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStringRequest]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    id jsonResult = [self parseJsonResult:result];

    NSLog(@"Json Result Woop: %@", jsonResult);
```

the parseJsonResult is exactly the same as the one that was on the link. My problem is though, whenever I would show the **jsonResult** on the NSLog, it would show the json result which is:

```
Json Result Woop: {
    Authenticated = 0;
    Message = "Invalid Log In.";
}
```

But I'm not really sure how I can go into the variable and retrieve the key and it's value one by one.

I tried to do this:

```
NSError *jsonParseError = nil;
NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonParseError];
if(!jsonArray)
    NSLog(@"Parse error: %@", jsonParseError);
else
    for(NSDictionary *item in jsonArray)
        NSLog(@"%@", item);
```

using the **result** variable but it would just give me the keys.

Not really sure what to do.

Comment: hii , will you please tell me how you call the wcf web service successfully i tried your code and also the minthos code you referred from but i am not able to made the call to wcf from code.. plese do me help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JsonResult is already an NSDictionary as evidenced by NSLog showing it like this with curly braces. Just use

```
jsonResult[@"Message"]
```

to get to the value for the Message key.